# Are these statements equivalent about eigenvalues?

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra

I shall show that the zeros of a given function $f_{n+1}$ are the eigenvalues of a tridiagonal matrix $M$.
Pay attention that the coefficients of $f_{n+1}$ are also in the matrix $M$.
Would it suffice if I would show that $f_{n+1}$ is the characteristic polynomial of $M$ ? And just calculate the characteristical polynom of $M$ ?

Let $f_{n}=(x-a_n)f_{n-1}-b_nf_{n-2}$ be a recursiv formula with $f_0:=1$ and $f_{-1}:=0$.
Let $M$ be of the form: $$\begin{pmatrix} 
a_1 & 1 & 0  & 0 &\cdots 
\\b_2 & a_2 & 1 & 0 &\cdots
\\ \vdots
\\0 & \cdots & &b_{n+1} &a_{n+1}
\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: can you please explain more the context I personally don't
understand the hypothesis and the conclusion of the problem: what
is $n+1$?

Comment: @m-idaya: OK, give me 10 minutes to type

Comment: What does it mean "the entries of $f_{n+1}$ are also in the matrix $M$"?

Comment: @user84976: I mean that the coefficients of $f_{n+1}$ are also entries of the matrix $M$.

Comment: thanks, but what is $b_1$ in the recursiv formula,ok, $f_{-1}=0$

Comment: So you have just to show that the zeros of $f_n$ are the eigen values of $M$? In this case, yes, you can just show that $f_n$ is the characteristical polynomial (by recursion on the determinant of $\lambda I-M$). In general it's true that eigenvalues coincides with roots of characteristical polynomial (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_polynomial)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

let $M_{n+1}=\left(\begin{array}{ccccc} a_1 & 1 & 0  & 0 &\cdots
\\b_2 & a_2 & 1 & 0 &\cdots
\\ \vdots
\\0 & \cdots & &b_{n+1} &a_{n+1}
\end{array}\right)$
and let the polynomial defined recursively by
$f_{n}(X)=(x-a_n)f_{n-1}(X)-b_nf_{n-2}(X)$  for $n\geq 1$ and
$f_0=1, f_{-1}=0$ then we must prove
 by recurrence on
$n$ and  a calculation of the determinant ( development of the
determinant following the last line of $M_{n+1}$) we get the
result as $f_{n+1}(X)=det(M_{n+1}-XI_n)$ that is the
characteristic polynomial of $M_{n+1}$.

add to my answer:

to show that the roots of a polynomial function
$f$ are eigenvalue of a matrix $M$, it suffices to show that this
polynomial divides the characteristic polynomial of $M$ or
equivalently the minimal polynomial of $M$ .

to show that the roots of a polynomial function $f$ are exactly
the eigenvalue of $M$ with the same order of multiplicity it is
necessary and sufficient to show that $f$ is the characteristic
polynomial of $M$ (modulo multiplication by a nonzero constant).

Answer (score 0):

We have $f_{n}+a_nf_{n-1}+b_nf_{n-2}=xf_{n-1}$. Let $F_n = [f_0, f_1, \dots, f_n]^T$. Then, from this recursion:
$$f_{n+1}e_{n+1}+MF_n=xF_n$$
where $e_{n+1}$ is the last column of $(n+1) \times (n+1)$ identity matrix. Let $x$ be the zero of $f_{n+1}$. Then
$$MF_n=xF_n$$
Thus, $x$ is an eigenvalue of $M$ and $F_n$ is the associated eigenvector.